# Mock local variable derived from redux store redux saga testing

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, redux-saga

I have written a saga that uses a `yield select` to get part of the redux store state and store it in a local variable.  The variable is an object with three different keys and each key's value is an array of objects within that.

My redux-saga tests keep failing because I create this local variable within the saga that uses data from the initial `yield select` and in the tests that variable is always `undefined`, which causes the rest of my tests in that saga to fail.   I've seen a lot of examples about how to mock the return state of `yield select` in a redux saga, but it's always in the context of the next redux-saga call.  How do I mock the return state for a local variable?

Here is my code:

```
export default function* orderSelectionFlow({ payload }) {
  try {
    const orders = yield select(getOrders); // retrieve relevant part of redux store
    const activeOrder = orders[payload.orderStatus].find(order => order.id === payload.orderId); // this variable is always undefined in my tests, because I am not sure how to mock `orders` for a local variable.
    const activeOrderId = payload.orderId;
    const isConnected = yield select(getIsConnected); // test for this select fails because activeOrder is undefined
```

My test ( up to the relevant point) is

```
describe('test order selection flow', () => {
  const navSpy = jest.spyOn(AppNavigator, 'navigate');
  const action = {
    type: 'galactica/orders/VIEW',
    payload: {
      orderStatus: 'OPEN',
      orderId: 1
    }
  };

  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    navSpy.mockRestore();
  });
  it.next = sagaHelper(orderSelectionFlow(action));

  it.next('should get all orders', (result) => {
    expect(result).toEqual(select(getOrders));
  });

  it.next('should use connected state', (result) => {
    expect(result).toEqual(select(getIsConnected));
  });
```

Orders is currently undefined, but if I could mock the value it would be

`orders: { 
    'OPEN': { 
         orderId: 1 
    } 
 }`

Comment: any chance you can help me with my question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59976240/how-to-write-a-redux-saga-test-by-mocking-selectors-and-or-redux-store

Answer (score 0):

I would try using `redux-saga-tester`: https://github.com/wix/redux-saga-tester . It let's you specifiy the initial state in the options. I'm not quite sure what all your code looks like, but I think you could do something like below.

```
describe('test order selection flow', () => {
  const navSpy = jest.spyOn(AppNavigator, 'navigate');
  const action = {
    type: 'galactica/orders/VIEW',
    payload: [{
      orderStatus: 'OPEN',
      orderId: 1
    }]
  };

  afterAll(() => {
    jest.resetModules();
    navSpy.mockRestore();
  });

  it('should get all orders', (result) => {
    const tester = new SagaTester({
       initialState: {
         orders: { 
           'OPEN': { 
             orderId: 1 
           } 
         }
       }
    });

    tester.start(saga);
    tester.dispatch(action);

    // ... do your expects here
    // You may need to use `tester.waitFor` to wait for an action to be dispatched
    // If you want to expect a certain action was called, use `getCalledActions`
  });
```